# mySql fire trigger only when a certain column is updated in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a trigger on a table that's fired when the table gets updated.

Problem is, I need that trigger to fire only when a certain column is updated. Right now, the trigger runs when any column is updated (I learned the hard way).

How can I get the trigger to run only when a particular column is updated. For example:

```
col1 | col2
-----------
```

The trigger should run only if `col1` is updated and not if any other column is updated. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

MySQL does not support firing a trigger on a specific column change. But you can check if a specific column changed in your trigger like this

```
delimiter $$
create trigger col1_trigger before insert on your_table
for each row begin 
  if NEW.col1 <> OLD.col1
  then 
    ...
  end if;
end 
$$
```

Comment: Of course, this method won't account for changes from a NULL to a value or the other way around.